# Medium-editor.js ни в какую не работает

Tags: javascript

Подскажите идиоту(мне) что я делаю не так) Подключил редактор с оф.сайта, пробую на заголовок вешать, и почти все функции не работают.
http://vh17725.hv4.ru/ вот пример где висит редактор. Всего один тэг и тот не работает. В хроме все прекрасно а вот в ff нифига не работает. Хотя на демке в фаерфокс все норм

Comment: Советую не пользоваться им. Как то я встроил его в CMS и пожалел, так как документация крайне скудная. Плагинов мало. В общем - дохлый проект.

Comment: @VladimirMorulus есть альтернативы?)